# Java Two Dimensional Array Definition

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, definition, dimensions

I have quite a basic question.

For example:

```
int a[][] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}
```

we say it is [3][4] as it has 3 elements and each element has its own 4 elements.

but how about:

```
int a[][] = {{1},{5,6,7},{9,10,11,12}}
```

is it still [3][4]?

---

**update**

so based on the helpful comments below, my first example can be written as a [3][4] array, but the second one cannot be indicated like that, right?

Comment: in both cases you have array of arrays, just in first example all lengths are same

Comment: In regards to your update, that is correct.

Answer (score 6):

These are called [Jagged Arrays](http://way2java.com/arrays/jagged-arrays-varying-column-size-arrays/), and they are not considered to be [m-by-n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28math%29#Size), because they do not fit the formal definition of a [Matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29).

> In mathematics, a matrix (plural matrices) is a *rectangular* array of numbers, symbols, or expressions, arranged in rows and columns.

Answer (score 3):

According to java

> A multidimensional array is an array whose components are themselves arrays. This is unlike arrays in C or Fortran. A consequence of this is that the rows are allowed to vary in length.

Take `int a[][]={{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12}}`

Here you can't say [3][4] array,but can say  it has 3 elements and each element has its own 4 elements.

Take `int a[][]={{1},{5,6,7},{9,10,11,12}}`
So here you can say array has 3 elements and each element has different number of elements.

Comment: so only the array of array has same length of column can be called [m][n], yes?

Comment: @WangPeiTheDancer yes they only follow the definition of matrix

Answer (score 2):

I just did this test on an Android environment, which will probably work for this case scenario (I think)

```
int a[][] = { { 1 }, { 5, 6, 7 }, { 9, 10, 11, 12 } };
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        Log.i("", "i: " + i);
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            Log.i("", "j: " + j);
        }
}
```

What I got was:

```
i: 0
j: 0
i: 1
j: 0
j: 1
j: 2
i: 2
j: 0
j: 1
j: 2
j: 3
```

So, `a` is not  `int[3][4]`.

Comment: so only the array of array has same length of column can be called [m][n], yes?

Comment: [m][n] refer to the number of columns and row.  Each intersection of [m] and [n] must be filled with a value in order to be considered a matrix.  Else wise its a jagged array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not [3][4].

Its **array of array** where external array is of dimension "3" and array elements, which are again array, of varying length i.e. 1, 3 and 4 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. When you go like `int[][] test = new int[3][4]` that's just syntactic sugar. There's nothing magical about a double array.

Both examples are arrays of arrays. Your first happens to have all of those arrays the same legnth ,your second does not.

As a side comment, the vast majority of java programmers use `int[][] a` notation, rather than `int a[][]` notation.

Answer (score 0):

There are no 2-dimensional arrays in Java.

There only exist arrays of arrays, **where each array can have a different length**.

For matrixes, consider a linear memory layout, and using one of the existing libraries.

Note that the following is valid in Java:

```
int[][] example = new int[2][2];
example[0] = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
```

while a proper matrix module will not allow this to happen.

This is **both a strength and a weakness**. There are applications where you just *need* arrays-of-arrays. And there are cases where it is more efficient (e.g. storing half a triangular matrix only).